# Update Tkinter from within an Exscript function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a Python script that uses Exscript to log into network switches to gather information. I'm using Tkinter to present a graphical interface.
I'm trying to create a canvas window with status so that when the "go" button is clicked, the status windows is made visible and as the script logs into devices a label on the status window is updated (logging into device x of y).
I found the .update() and .update_idletasks(), which works when I enter the initial function (clicking the go button), but updating the label happens 2 functions deep in the Exscript start() function. In there anything I do to my canvas causes the script to hang and I have to force close it.

```
onhost = 0
hostcount = 0
def go_main():
 canvas.itemconfig(statuswindow, state='normal')
 canvas.itemconfig(statuslabel_window, state='normal')
 canvas.update()
 filename = InvEntry.get()
 accounts = [Account(unameEntry.get(), pwordEntry.get())]
 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
 sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("Infrastructure")
 global hostcount
 hostcount = sheet.nrows
 hosts = []
 for x in range (1, hostcount):
  hosts.append(conproto.get() + "://" + sheet.cell_value(x, 0))
 start(accounts, hosts, login_func)

def login_func(job, host, conn):
 global onhost
 global hostcount
 onhost = onhost + 1
 newstat = "Gathering MACs on switch %s of %s..." % (onhost, hostcount)
 stat.set(newstat)
 #canvas.update()
 conn.execute('term len 0') #We don't want a pause in the output
 conn.execute('sh ver') #Make sure we're a Nexus or Catalyst switch before continuing
 r = conn.response
 if r != '' and ('nx-os' or 'catalyst') in r.lower(): 
  #Grab the device's hostname:
```

As soon as it hits the "stat.set(newstat)" line it hangs. What am I doing wrong? Sorry if I slaughtered all the programmer lingo, I'm a network engineer pretending to be a programmer. Thanks!